# Two divs setting up fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have two HTML div blocks one is

DIV 1 has position:relative;

DIV 2 has position:fixed;

Is there a way to make the Fixed div block get the x position of the other one.

its a ASP.net user control that is used multiple times through out the website, to search for suppliers and i want the popup to always be inline with the search box

many thanks

Comment: position fixed start from top-left of the browser. If you want to make one relative to another then you have to use position relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you were looking for, but I think you wanted your pop up to be inline with the search box. Here's the css for the same:

```
#one{
position:relative;
width:100px;
border: 1px;
display:inline-block;
}
#two{
position:fixed;
width:100px;
border:1px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Here's a fiddle for the same:
http://jsfiddle.net/5RQFy/